# How i can reused/compose part of a JOOQ query in a repository method?

Tags: kotlin, jooq

With a JOOQ `DSLContext` variable `ctx` I have a method to select all relationship data.

```
 open fun selectAllSomethings(id: String): List<SomeDto> = ctx
    .select(..), 
    .from(..)
    .join(..)
    .leftJoin(...)
    .fetch()
    .map()
```

And I need to reused this logic with an `add` method where for a concrete `id` I want to change the code to use `fetchOne` and `map`. How can I reuse the first part of query and share it between both methods?  This part:

```
ctx.select(..), 
    .from(..)
    .join(..)
    .leftJoin(...)
```

Is it necessary to divide this into two different methods?  Or need to add an `if` ?

Comment: Answer below is based on assumptions because very little working code, or what you previously attempted was shown, and I added the assumption this was JOOQ library being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is not syntactically perfect -- without having your generated model, nor knowing the full types I can only show a rough sample.  The solution would basically be a shared method used by two other methods:

```
private fun DSLContext.baseThingQuery(id: String): ResultQuery<Record> {
    return select(...)
            .from(...)
            .join(...).on(...)
            .leftJoin(...).on(...)
} 

fun fetchAllThings(id: String): List<ThingDto> {
     return ctx.baseThingQuery(id).fetch(...).map(...)
}

fun doSomethignWithOneThing(id: String): ThingDto {
     return ctx.baseThingQuery(id).fetchOne(...).map(...)
}
```

**Note:**  *I made the shared utility function extend the `DSLContext` just so that it is more obvious that it is intended as a function to only be used within a context (i.e. transaction) and also `private` to make it truly internal.  You could easily change this to pass in the context as a parameter.*

Comment: Interesting approach! This allows for completely new mini-SQL language extensions based on jOOQ. Minor nit-pick: I'd return a `ResultQuery<Record>` type unless it is very clear that `SelectOnConditionStep` is a desireable return type (i.e. allowing the call-site to modify the last `leftJoin` predicate)

Comment: Thanks Lukas for the tip, I let type inference pick the return type which is too specific, so I updated to the `ResultQuery<Record>` as suggested, thanks for that!